# Find elements by name under a div in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the NodeList of  tags under a specific  by name but I'm unable to do so.
I have a function which is triggered on the 'click' event on a button.

```
let button = event.target;
let shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement;
let price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName("shop-item-price")[0].innerText; 
let sizePrices = document.getElementsByName("sizes");
```

Now, the hierarchy of the elements is as follows. `console.log(shopItem)` is equivalent to the following:-

```
<div class="shop-item" id="2">
      <span class="shop-item-title">Veggie Supreme</span>
      <img class="shop-item-img" src="Images/pizza.png" width="200" height="200">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
           <div class="shop-item-sizes">
                <input type="radio" value="100" name="sizes">
                <label>Small</label>
                <input type="radio" value="200" name="sizes">
                <label>Medium</label>
                <input type="radio" value="300" name="sizes">
                <label>Large</label>
            </div>
            <span class="shop-item-price">Rs.Rs.250</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button">ADD TO CART</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

I want to make use of shopItem to find elements by name "sizes" but I'm unable to use `shopItem.getElementsByName` and that is why I'm using `document.getElementsByName` but this gives me all the  tags in the entire page. I only want "sizes" under shopItem.
How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.shop-item [name="sizes"]');

console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div class="shop-item" id="2">
      <span class="shop-item-title">Veggie Supreme</span>
      <img class="shop-item-img" src="Images/pizza.png" width="200" height="200">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
           <div class="shop-item-sizes">
                <input type="radio" value="100" name="sizes">
                <label>Small</label>
                <input type="radio" value="200" name="sizes">
                <label>Medium</label>
                <input type="radio" value="300" name="sizes">
                <label>Large</label>
            </div>
            <span class="shop-item-price">Rs.Rs.250</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button">ADD TO CART</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried it. I have multiple items on my web page.. where each item has 3 <input> tags. I tried the above code and the 'nodes' always correspond to the first item <input> tags.

Comment: Well, it shows me all the <input> tags now. I have total 12 <input> tags.. it shows me all of them when I do console.log(nodes)

Answer (score 0):

```
let sizePrices = shopItem.getElementsByClassName("sizes");
<div class = "shop-item-sizes">
      <input type="radio" value="100" name="sizes" class="sizes">
      <label>Small</label>
      <input type="radio" value="200" name="sizes" class="sizes" >
      <label>Medium</label>
      <input type="radio" value="300" name="sizes" class="sizes">
      <label>Large</label>
</div>
```

I assigned a class to the  tag. Doesn't seem to be the efficient way but it works for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div.shop-item-sizes > input[name="sizes"]');
console.log(nodes);
```

In case you want to convert it to an array.

```
const nodesArray = Array.from(nodes);
console.log(nodesArray);
```